# Want to calculate cumulative sum and % across hierarchical data in pandas/python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to calculate cumulative sum and % for data in which a parent/child relationship exists, but want the cumulative sum and cum $ to be the same for all children of a given parent.

Suppose the following table

```
import pandas as pd
imp = [{'Parent':'A', 'Child':'B', 'Value': 5}
    , {'Parent':'C', 'Child':'D', 'Value': 4}
    , {'Parent':'C', 'Child':'E', 'Value': 7}
    , {'Parent':'F', 'Child':'G', 'Value': 6}
    ]
df=pd.DataFrame(imp)
print(df)
```

The resulting DataFrame:

```
Parent  Child   Value
A       B       5
C       D       4
C       E       7
F       G       6
```

I want to calculate the cumulative sum and % such that I would get the following:

```
Parent  Child   Value   CumSum  cumPct
C       D       4       11      0.5
C       E       7       11      0.5
F       G       6       17      0.772727273
A       B       5       22      1
```

I know how to normally calculate cumulative sum, but the method I am familar with doesn't work on this type of parent/child structure and will give me incorrect values.

Appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: How do you sort the rows before you calculate the cumsum? Is there any logic?

Comment: `cumsum` for your first row is 4 and not 11

Comment: ombk - thats the point actually, the cumulative sum is effectively by parent, so it would be 11 on both first and second row. I was able to get the calc I wanted by doing  a groupby on the parents to get the parent level sum, doing sort & cumsum on that set, then joining back into the original table. I figure there has to be better way though.

Comment: mosc9575 - they would need to be sorted by the aggregate at the parent level